# how to autosum the values gotten from an ajax strings

Tags: jquery, ajax

Please, i have a script that auto sum values being typed into table cells, it gives the remark and grade based on the total values in plain html page. how can i auto sum same values gotten from an ajax return strings. below is the ajax return strings

```
//Ajax return strings
$.each(result, function(key, value)
{
string += "<tr class='rowca'><td>#</td><td>" +value.sID+ "</td><td>" 
+value['Full Names']+ "</td><td><input type='text' name='ca1[]' id='ca1' 
class='entry' maxlength='2' value='" +value.ca1+ "'></td><td><input 
type='text' name='ca2[]' id='ca2' class='entry' maxlength='2' value='" 
+value.ca2+ "'></td><td><input type='text' name='ca3[]' id='ca3' 
class='entry' maxlength='2' value='" +value.ca3+ "'></td><td><input 
type='text' name='ca4[]' id='ca4' class='entry' maxlength='2' value='" 
+value.exam+ "'></td><td><input type='text' name='ca5[]' id='ca5' 
class='total' disabled value='" +value.total+ "'></td><td><input type='text' 
name='ca6[]' id='ca6' class='demo' disabled value='" +value.grade+ "'></td>
<td><input type='text' name='ca7[]' id='ca7' class='remark' disabled 
value='" +value.remarks+ "'></td></tr><input type='text' id='sid[]' value='" 
+value.sID+ "'>";
});

//Below is the script that works on the plain html page
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('rowca');
[].forEach.call(rows, function(rowca){
rowca.addEventListener('keyup', function()
    {
      var demos =  rowca.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0];
      var gtotal = rowca.getElementsByClassName('total');
      var entries = rowca.getElementsByClassName('entry');
      var remarks = rowca.getElementsByClassName('remark')[0];

      var score = [].reduce.call(entries, function(sum, entry)
            {
                return +entry.value + sum;
            }, 0);

      gtotal.value = score || 0;
      demos.value = getGrade(score);
      remarks.value = getRemark(score);
  });
});

function getGrade(score) 
{
    if (score > 90) { return 'A+'; }
  else if (score > 80) { return 'A'; }
  else if (score > 70) { return 'B+'; }
  else if (score > 60) { return 'B'; }
  else if (score > 50) { return 'C'; }
  else if (score > 40) { return 'D'; }
  else if (score > 30) { return 'E'; }
  else if (score >= 0) { return 'F'; }
  else { return 'No grade yet'; }
}

function getRemark(score)
{
       if (score > 90) { return 'Excellent'; }
  else if (score > 80) { return 'Distinction'; }
  else if (score > 70) { return 'Very Good'; }
  else if (score > 60) { return 'Good'; }
  else if (score > 50) { return 'Credit'; }
  else if (score > 40) { return 'Pass'; }
  else if (score > 30) { return 'Poor'; }
  else if (score >= 0) { return 'Fail'; }
  else { return 'No grade yet'; }
}

});
```

Comment: @kennasoft i have posted my question thanks

Comment: @kennasoft Please any help with the above question i have submitted

Comment: @kennasoft Thanks anyway i have solve my challenge.